# How do I modify this jQuery to add an active class to the selected link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".page-contents div").hide();
          // Show chosen div, and hide all others
        jQuery("a").click(function (e) {
            //e.preventDefault();
            jQuery("#" + jQuery(this).attr("class")).show().siblings('div').hide();
        });
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fXE9p/

Could someone explain how I go about modifying this code so that it adds an "active" class to the selected link, and how it works? Thank you kindly in advance

Answer (score 0):

Following code adds `active` class to clicked link:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".page-contents div").hide();
    // Show chosen div, and hide all others
    jQuery("a").click(function (e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        //jQuery("#" + jQuery(this).attr("class")).show().siblings('div').hide();
      jQuery(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```